# Building docker images from a source directory using different dockerfiles

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My goal is to build several different docker images , from the same source code.

i have my ./src folder (node.js project).
inside ./src  i have first.dockerfile and second dockerfile.

for building the the project i use this standard command line

```
sudo docker build -t doronaviugy/myproject .
```

This works with no problems using the default **Dockerfile**

I'm trying to build it from a specific dockerfile using the line

```
sudo docker build -t doronaviguy/myproject  - <   first.docker
```

this line works, but now path doesn't being copy inside the image

```
#Inside the Dockerfile
ADD . /src
```

I think i understand how to specify a dockerfile argument, but i need to specify a direcotry argument to be copied inside the docker image.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Since Docker 1.5, you can use the `-f` argument to select the Dockerfile to use e.g:

`docker build -t doronaviugy/myproject -f dockerfiles/first.docker .`

If you use stdin to build your image ( the `- < first.docker` syntax), you won't have a build context so you will be unable to use `COPY` or `ADD` instructions that refer to local files.

If you have to use an older version of Docker, you'll need to use some scripting to copy your specific Dockerfiles to `Dockerfile` at the root of the build context before calling `docker build`.

Comment: Thanks , i did to try to use the -f argument , but with no success, and then i noticed i had to upgrade my docker version to 1.5 .

Comment: @Adrian Mouat  can you take a look here what i am doing wrong https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60407265/docker-connection-error-connection-broken-by-newconnectionerror/60407542?noredirect=1#comment106864535_60407542