# Docker connection error 'Connection broken by NewConnectionError'

Tags: django, python-3.x, docker, dockerfile

I am new to docker i just installed it and did some configuration for my django project.
when i am running **`docker build .`** i am getting these error **whats wrong here?**

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f1363b604f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Try again')': /simple/django/
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine
MAINTAINER RAHUL VERMA

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR app
COPY ./app /app

RUN adduser -D user
USER user
```

**requirements.txt file**

```
Django==2.2
djangorestframework==3.11.0
```

Comment: check your internet connection.....

Comment: i tried on different different networks & got the same error.

Comment: that has nothing to do with docker network, check if you are behinde a proxy or something prevent you to have a stable connection to the internet

Comment: proxy server is already off in my system settings

Answer (score 0):

I just do small changes to use your dockerfile and run command **docker build -t app dockerfilelocation**. 
Its working from my side.My dockerfile look like -

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine
MAINTAINER RAHUL VERMA

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY . /app/
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR app
COPY ./app /app

RUN adduser -D user
USER user
```

Comment: `docker build -t app` it gives error `"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.`

Comment: i am already on dockerfile location in cmd while running  `docker build -t app Dockerfile` (here Dockerfile is name of my docker file) it gives error  `invalid argument "Dockerfile" '

Comment: the command **docker build -t app .** where dot tell that current dir and if your dockerfile is another dir then your command, **docker build -t app -f dirlocation .** example if your dockerfile is in test dir then your command is **docker build -t app -f /test .** you can also take help from here -
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29409310/building-docker-images-from-a-source-directory-using-different-dockerfiles

Comment: i am in the same Dockerfile directory but still getting same error.

Comment: I tried  `docker build .`, `docker build -t app Dockerfile` & `docker build -t app . ` these all give the same error.

Comment: what is the of your dockerfile? Its it **Dockerfile** or something else

Comment: It's Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem it I solveit with the conections of internet or you can check it with this:

"This is almost certainly an issue with the networking/DNS configuration inside the container and not related to pip specifically. Try adding a **RUN nslookup pypi.org** line to your Dockerfile and see if it works. If you're using a custom index URL then put that instead of pypi.org."

https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7460